# Replacing a colon using string replace using Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, string

I have a simple string that I'm trying to manipulate:

> Your order will be processed soon:

I grab the string using:

```
var html = jQuery('.checkout td h4').html();
```

I then try to replace the ':' using:

```
html.replace(":", ".");
```

When I print it out to the console, the string is the same as the original string. I've also tried making sure that the `html` variable is of type "string" by doing the following:

```
html = html + "";
```

That doesn't do anything. In searching around, it seems that the `replace` function does a RegEx search and that the ":" character might have a special meaning. I do not know how to fix this. Can someone help me get rid of this stinkin' colon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `replace` function returns a new string with the replacements made.
Javascript strings are immutable—it *cannot* modify the original string.

You need to write `html = html.replace(":", ".");`

Comment: Could of sworn I tried that and it didn't work...oh well...it is certainly working now. Thanks! I'll give you the check when it lets me in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Slightly related...

I couldn't get these answers to work to replace all ":" in a string for the url encoded character %3a and modified this answer by'xdazz' to work: [Javascript: Replace colon and comma characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248042/javascript-replace-colon-and-comma-characters) to get...

```
str = str.replace(/:\s*/g, "%3a");
```

In your case it would be

```
str = str.replace(/:\s*/g, ".");
```

If you wanted to replace all colons with periods on a longer string.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I think c++ is the only high level language where strings are mutable. This means that `replace` cannot modify the string it operates on and so must return a new string instead.

Try the following instead

```
var element = jQuery('.checkout td h4');

element.html(element.html().replace(":", "."));
```

Or, perhaps more correctly (since you may have multiple elements).

```
jQuery('.checkout td h4').html(
    function (index, oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.replace(":", ".");
    }
 );
```