# Javascript: Replace colon and comma characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Relative newcomer to Javascript and a bit stuck with the following so would greatly appreciate some help...

I have a string made up of a list of categories and keywords which might appear like:

```
Category A:Keyword A, Category B:, Category C: Keyword B
```

The problem is displaying a category when there is no keyword - how can I do a Find and Replace to swap instances of `:,` with just `,`?

I already use the following to insert a space after the comma:

```
cats = cats.replace(/,/g,", ");
```

but copying and modifying with the extra colon seems to break it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
cats = cats.replace(/:\s*,/g,", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use arrays:

```
var arr="Category A:Keyword A, Category B:, Category C:Keyword B".split(', ');
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   arr[i]=arr[i].split(':');
}
```

Then, `arr` becomes `[["Category A", "Keyword A"], ["Category B", ""], ["Category C", "Keyword B"]]`