# Remove special characters from input field

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, onchange

I've been searching everywhere but have been unable to find exactly what I am looking for.

I have an html form that is filled out with Mac addresses from our inventory so the strings inputted into the input field will look like:

A1:A2:A3:A4:A5:A6

I'm trying to write a script to remove the `:` character plus any spaces anywhere.  That way when it is entered the output will be:

A1A2A3A4A5A6

This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="text" id="macaddress" onChange="removeChar();WriteLog();" />
```

Then in my script I have:

```
function removeChar() {
  var a = document.getElementById("macaddress").value;
  a = a.replace(/: /g, '');
  document.getElementById.innerHTML = a;
}
```

I don't get any JavaScript errors with this but nothing happens.

I also have another script that pulls the value of the field into a work log which is the other function `WriteLog()`.

Essentially I want to remove the `:` then have the new value pulled into the log by the second function.

Comment: You have your regex as ": ", it should be ":" (no spaces).  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6525002/2430549

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a colon using string replace using Javascript and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524982/replacing-a-colon-using-string-replace-using-javascript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question spec says you want to remove `:` and `:` with space. Make the space in the regex optional:

`a = a.replace(/:( )?/g, '');`

But you also need to account for preceeding spaces:

`a = a.replace(/( )?:( )?/g, '');`

I would also trim the initial string (Just good practice)

`a = a.trim().replace(/( )?:( )?/g, '');`

Finally, I am not sure what this line does:
`document.getElementById.innerHTML = a;`, but that line will throw an error. Remove it.

Comment: Why do you suggest him to remove the last line, he probably needs it, just needs to fix it.

Comment: Perfect the trim worked. I had to combine it with my first function to pull the data but it worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep only numbers and letts you can use this

```
a.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

which basically replaces everything that isn't a-z or A-Z or 0-9 with an empty string.

A great tool for explaining regex and testing it is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

And this line `document.getElementById.innerHTML = a;` should be fixed as well, you probably meant something like `document.getElementById('some-elements-id').innerHTML = a;`

Comment: `<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/g, '')" >` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

to remove colons and spaces from string simply use

```
str = str.replace(/[:\s]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="macaddress"/>
<button onclick="removeChar()">Click me!</button>
```

JS

```
function removeChar() {
    var a = document.getElementById("macaddress").value.trim();
    a = a.split('');
    a.forEach(function (character, index) {
        if (character === ':') {
            a.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    a = a.join('');
    document.getElementById("macaddress").value  = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex searches for "colon immediately followed by space".

If you add a **pipe** in between them: `/:| /`, then it will search for all colons and/or spaces, in any order.

Demo:

```js
function removeChar() {
  var a = document.getElementById("macaddress").value;
  a = a.replace(/:| /g, '');
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="macaddress" onChange="removeChar();" />
<div id="result"></div>
```